# How to prove that a predicate is prefix closed

Tags: logic, proof-techniques, first-order-logic

Suppose we have the predicate

$\qquad A.p.q ≡ (∀i \mid p≤i≤j<q : X.i≤X.j)$

which says that $X[p..q)$ is ascending.

Apparently, the predicate holds for empty segments, is prefix closed and is postfix closed.

I would like to prove that the predicate above is indeed prefix closed, but I am not able to; that is, I am unable to prove that

$\qquad A.p.q \implies (∀s \mid p≤s≤q : A.p.s)$

and I wondered if somebody could help?

Comment: What are the formal definitions of a predicate being prefix resp. postfix closed?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear: the proposition (the second one in my post ) I am trying to prove is the formal definition of prefix closed.  I can't figure out how to show how the given A.p.q satisfies it.

Comment: Hint: every $j$ can be a $q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predicate states that $X_p \leq X_{p+1} \leq \cdots \leq X_{q-1}$. If you take any subinterval of $[p,q)$, say $[p',q')$, you will still have $X_{p'} \leq X_{p'+1} \leq \cdots \leq X_{q'}$. In other words, a subinterval of a non-decreasing sequence is also non-decreasing.

Now that you know why what you want to prove is true, it remains to prove it formally. Always remember: the first step is to understand *why* something is true, and only then should you try to prove it. In fact, most of the time in mathematics and computer science we skip the second step, that of proving things formally, since it obscures the situation.

Comment: I thought that's what it meant, and now I know. Thanks! It's the formal proof I'm having difficulty with.  Is it apropriate for me to try to write a proof and post it for someone to check?

Comment: We usually don't check people's proofs, that's your grader's job.

Comment: That's rather presumptuous of you: I am pursuing this knowledge out of love, not in pursuit of a qualification.

Comment: In that case, you're out of luck. Most people asking this type of question are really asking for help solving their homework.

Comment: @Adam, Yes, you should try to write a proof ... but you'll need to check it yourself.  I'm afraid asking others to check your proof isn't the sort of thing this site is set up for.  Our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will be useful to others (not just to you), and a question asking people to check your proof would likely not be of much use to others, so it's not a good fit for this site.  Sorry to disappoint.

Comment: Not at all. Thanks for your guidance.  I genuinely am pursuing this because I love it, and I only posted after trying for two weeks on my own.  Thanks again.